# link 1 shifts down for a split second when clicking link 2 during toggle

Tags: css, toggle

For my website, I want to include a CSS-based link that toggles from "**More info +**" and "**Less Info -**", which reveals the hidden text. I wrote the code, which seems to work, however the second "Less Info" is clicked, the text and content shifts down for a split second. Is there any way to fix this minor issue?

Please take a look at the JSFiddle code below to see the unwanted shift in action.
http://jsfiddle.net/kenhimself/hf1hxrhq/

HTML

```
<div id="show"> <a href="#show" id="open" class="toggletitle">More Info +</a>

    <div id="content"> <a href="#hide" id="close" class="toggletitle">Less Info –</a>

        <p>The second “Less info” is pressed, the “More Info” abruptly appears, shifting the “Less Info” text downwards for a split second.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- END Content -->
</div>
<!-- END Show -->
```

CSS

```
html, html a, body {
    text-decoration: none;
}
/* Requesting assistance START */
 #content {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: visibility 0s linear 0.5s, opacity 0.5s linear;
}
#show:target #content {
    display: inline-block;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
#show:target #open {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
/* Requesting assistance END */

/* Link Hover Properties */
 .toggletitle {
    font-size: 20px;
}
a:link {
    -webkit-transition:color .1s ease-in;
    -moz-transition:color .1s ease-in;
    -o-transition:color .1s ease-in;
    transition:color .1s ease-in;
    color: #000;
}
a:visited {
    color: #000;
}
a:hover {
    -webkit-transition:color 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition:color 0.5s ease-out;
    color: #0000FF;
}
a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the `More Info` div over the less one. Since you are animating less but not more that flicks. Try adding this:

```
#show {
    position:relative;
}
#open {
    position:Absolute;
    background:#fff;
    z-index:10;
}
```

Check the [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hf1hxrhq/1/)

Comment: Ah, yes, that did it!
However, I'm wondering if it's possible to add a fade effect on the links themselves? I'm still seeing flashes of white between the text transition--any way the fade can overlap?

Answer (score 1):

Another, more efficient approaches, could focus on restructuring markup a little and moving away from using `:target`.  Although `:target` is certainly workable, it gums up the history cache.

Solution #1 using `:focus` and `pointer-events`: http://jsfiddle.net/qjupvbju/.

HTML:

```
<div id="show">
    <a href = "#" tabindex = "1"><span>More Info +</span><span>Less Info -</span></a>
    <p>The second “Less info” is pressed, the “More Info” abruptly appears, shifting the “Less Info” text downwards for a split second.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
a, a:link, a:visited, a:focus, a:hover {
    color: #0000ff;
    outline: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#show > a:not(:focus) + p, 
#show > a:not(:focus) > span + span, 
#show > a:focus > span:first-of-type {
    opacity: 0;
}

#show > a {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#show > a > span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#show > a:focus > span + span {
    opacity: 1;
}

#show span,
#show p {
    transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
}

#show > a:focus {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Solution #2 using `checkbox input` to persist state and `:checked` pseudo-class: http://jsfiddle.net/ubv5x65c/.

HTML:

```
<div id="show">
    <input type = "checkbox" id = "toggle" />
    <label for = "toggle"><span>More Info +</span><span>Less Info -</span></label>
    <p>The second “Less info” is pressed, the “More Info” abruptly appears, shifting the “Less Info” text downwards for a split second.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#show > input[type = "checkbox"] {
    display: none;        
}

#show > input:not(:checked) + label > span + span,
#show > input:not(:checked) ~ p,
#show > input:checked + label > span:first-of-type {
    opacity: 0;
}

#show > label {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #00f;
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#show > label > span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#show > input:checked ~ p {
    opacity: 1;
}

#show span, 
#show p {
    transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment, however the solution you provided does disable the fade effect..

Comment: My post has been updated to keep the animations.  Here are the links: http://jsfiddle.net/qjupvbju/, http://jsfiddle.net/ubv5x65c/.